# Добавить картинку в PictureBox

Tags: c++-cli, picturebox

Как добавить картинку из папки "Файлы ресурсов" в picturebox?
Работаю с WinForms c++ cli.
Можно ли как-то нарисовать значение переменной, например, `int a=15;`, чтобы на picturebox добавить `15` как изображение?

[image: Структура проекта]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался

```
Bitmap^ bmp = gcnew Bitmap(450, 350);
Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(bmp); // холст для рисования
pictureBox1->Image = bmp; // закрепление к pictureBox

Bitmap^ image1; // фото загрузки в pictureBox

image1 = gcnew Bitmap("logo.bmp"); // инициализация файл с фото

pictureBox1->Image = image1;
```